# Starting Jupyter notebook on pycharm

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I've opened a new Jupyter notebook file, entered a few arguments in a cell and pressed the 'play' button.  It then asks me to confirm the Jupyter notebook URL, which I do (http://127.0.0.1:8888) and I get the following output:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future
usage: pycharm_load_entry_point.py [-h] [--ip NOTEBOOKAPP.IP]
                               [--keyfile NOTEBOOKAPP.KEYFILE]
                               [--transport KERNELMANAGER.TRANSPORT]
                               [--log-level NOTEBOOKAPP.LOG_LEVEL]
                               [--config NOTEBOOKAPP.CONFIG_FILE]
                               [--browser NOTEBOOKAPP.BROWSER]
                               [--certfile NOTEBOOKAPP.CERTFILE]
                               [--client-ca NOTEBOOKAPP.CLIENT_CA]
                               [--port NOTEBOOKAPP.PORT]
                               [--pylab [NOTEBOOKAPP.PYLAB]]
                               [--notebook-dir NOTEBOOKAPP.NOTEBOOK_DIR]
                               [--port-retries NOTEBOOKAPP.PORT_RETRIES]
                               [--generate-config] [--no-mathjax]
                               [--debug] [--script] [--no-script] [-y]
                               [--no-browser]
pycharm_load_entry_point.py: error: ambiguous option: --no could match --no-script, --notebook-dir, --no-mathjax, --no-browser
```

It will then try and connect but after a few seconds there is a message saying "Cannot connect to Jupyter Notebook: cannot connect to Jupyter server".

I've looked around online for an answer but haven't come across anyone else having had this problem.  Any help would be great.